# accumulo regex using egrep example

Tags: regex, grep, accumulo

Problem: data from one particular source into our accumulo instance is not being returned to our client application via a subset of our search interfaces.

When we use search method "A" we get results, but when we use search method "B" we do not.

I have a hunch that method "A" and method "B" are actually hitting different tables.
In order to prove that, I need a way to put a hook into the stream of data coming into the tables and grep for data indicating the source of the message. I can't do anything programatically because that would necessitate my taking the system down which isn't an option right now.

I see from the manual that there is a 'grep' and 'egrep' command. The help file on grep says not to use it for regex, and I can't seem to get egrep to return a record I know to be in the database.

**example:**
A record in the exchange contains the line `<gml:pos>23.05507 113.5268</gml:pos>`. To egrep for it, I log into the accumulo shell, select the table in which the record exists, then enter the following `egrep ^:pos>23.*113.*`.

Nothing comes back.
I've tried all the variants of the command I could think of (quoting, not quoting, searching only for 23.*, etc).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is incorrect.  Your's starts with `^:pos` which would mean "Match where :pos starts the record"

You need to change it to something like:

```
egrep "^.*pos>23.*113.*"
```

This says "Match any amount of any characters from the beggining to pos>23, then match any amount of characters until I see  113, then match any more characters". The key is the `.*` between `^` and `pos`

Do note, however that this will match ANYTHING that goes `pos>23`. For instance:

```
root@accumuloinstance testTable> insert "<gml:pos>23.05507 113.5268</gml:pos>" "" "" ""
root@accumuloinstance testTable> insert "<gml:pos>232.05507 113.5268</gml:pos>" "" "" ""
root@accumuloinstance testTable> insert "<gml:pos>232XXX113.5268</gml:pos>" "" "" ""
root@accumuloinstance testTable> egrep "^.*pos>23.*113.*"
<gml:pos>23.05507 113.5268</gml:pos> : []
<gml:pos>232.05507 113.5268</gml:pos> : []
<gml:pos>232XXX113.5268</gml:pos> : []
```

Don't know exactly what you're looking for, but you might want to try:

```
root@accumuloinstance testTable> egrep "^.*pos>23[.].* 113[.].*"
<gml:pos>23.05507 113.5268</gml:pos> : []
```

Which will match 23.xxxx 113.xxxxx so you get exactly 23.something and 113.something

If that doesn't give you your result you're looking for, try doing `egrep ".*"` If you don't get any records back then either you don't have any, or your visibilities don't match.

Comment: w00t - t/y! I'll try this when I get into the office tomorrow morning.

Comment: no go. attempted  egrep "^.*pos>22[.].* 113[.].*" against a table containing a record containing the line <gml:pos>22.31997 113.3154</gml:pos>. command egrep".*" returns a plethora of results.

Comment: How much data is in your table.  How is is layed out?  Can you do a scan and confirm that the row is actually there?

Comment: Do you *think* that row is there, or do you *know* its there.  (i.e. scan you do a scan and find it)?  Scan you egrep for any of the other values besides that particular value?

Comment: as far as I know there's millions of entries in the system. i know the data is there because I did a scan on the table and picked the first entry I found to craft an egrep query.

Comment: That's very odd.  I guess start broad and start working more narrow.  So first do a `egrep ".*05507.*".  You should get lots of records.  Then add more to the regex until it stops working and figure out why it stopped working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55731/discussion-between-user1146334-and-david-daedalus).

Answer (score -1):

The leading ^ in your regex appears to be anchoring ":pos" to the beginning of the line.  Since the line begins with "

```
$ echo '<gml:pos>23.05507 113.5268</gml:pos>' | egrep '^:pos>23.*113.*'
$ echo '<gml:pos>23.05507 113.5268</gml:pos>' | egrep ':pos>23.*113.*'
<gml:pos>23.05507 113.5268</gml:pos>
```

Comment: That works for regular command line `egrep` but in Accumulo that will not match